# Angular 4 - Add Class if ngModel is not empty

Tags: javascript, html, angular, if-statement, material-design

How can I add a class to an element on a page if my defined ngModel for a select element is not empty.  Currently have this..

```
<md-select placeholder="Location" name="location" [(ngModel)]="selectedLocation">
      <md-option *ngFor="let option of locationOptions" [value]="option.value">
        {{option.viewValue}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
```

And would like to add a class to a span element if the ngModel is not empty, something like this...

```
<p>Location:<span ng-class="{'complete': selectedLocation.length > 0}">{{ selectedLocation }}</span></p>
```

Comment: use `[ngClass]` instead. check docs `https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[ngClass]`

as [example from docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be between brackets to be binded to your variable. Also your ng-class attribute is wrong, it needs to be `ngClass`

```
<p>Location:<span [ngClass]="{'complete': selectedLocation.length > 0}">{{ selectedLocation }}</span></p>
```

Comment: I am receiving this in the console when I try your method above...'Can't bind to 'ng-class' since it isn't a known property of 'span'

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of angular4 but in angular 1 it goes in this way.

```
<div ng-class="{'myClass':myModel}"></div>
```

Comment: I missed to put my class under single quotes, try that. If still it does not work then someone who knows angular4 only can help you

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a case for the use of [class] as you have only one class to apply:

```
<p>Location:<span [class.complete]="selectedLocation.length > 0">{{ selectedLocation }}</span></p>
```

Much shorter I think.